# Insert multiple row from php page into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This problem's driving me crazy since yesterday. I have a table consist of 5 columns: kode_barang (item ID), nama_barang (name of item), qty (quantity), harga_beli (price), jumlah (total). User can input 2 items. This is the code of the form:

```
<HTML>
<?php include "koneksi.php"; ?>
<form action="insert3.php" method="POST">

<table id="theTable" border="1">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Kode Barang    </th>
        <th> Nama Barang </th>
        <th> Qty </th>
        <th> Harga Beli </th>
        <th> Jumlah </th>
    <tr> 
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td type="text" name="kode_barang" id="kode_barang1"/readonly>
            <?php  
                mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
                mysql_select_db("skripsi_1");  
                $result = mysql_query("select * from input_data_barang");  
                $met = "var kode_barang = new Array();\n";  
                echo '<select name="kode_barang" onchange="changeValue1(this.value)">';  
                echo '<option></option>';  
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
                echo '<option value="' . $row['kode_barang'] . '">' . $row['kode_barang'] . '</option>';  
                $met .= "kode_barang['" . $row['kode_barang'] . "'] = {name:'" . addslashes($row['nama_barang']) . "',desc:'".addslashes($row['nama_barang'])."'};\n";  
                } 
                echo '</select>';  
            ?>  
        </td>

        <td><input type="text" name="nama_barang" id="nama_barang1"/readonly>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                <?php echo $met; ?>
                function changeValue1(id){
                document.getElementById('kode_barang1').value = kode_barang[id].name;
                document.getElementById('nama_barang1').value = kode_barang[id].desc;
                };
            </script>
        </td>

        <td><input class="valOne" type="text" name="qty"></td>
        <td><input class="valTwo" type="text" name="harga_beli"></td>
        <td><input class="result" type="text" name="jumlah"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td type="text" name="kode_barang" id="kode_barang2"/readonly>
            <?php  
                mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
                mysql_select_db("skripsi_1");  
                $result = mysql_query("select * from input_data_barang");  
                $jsArray = "var kode_barang = new Array();\n";  
                echo '<select name="kode_barang" onchange="changeValue2(this.value)">';  
                echo '<option></option>';  
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
                echo '<option value="' . $row['kode_barang'] . '">' . $row['kode_barang'] . '</option>';  
                $jsArray .= "kode_barang['" . $row['kode_barang'] . "'] = {name:'" . addslashes($row['nama_barang']) . "',desc:'".addslashes($row['nama_barang'])."'};\n";  
                } 
                echo '</select>';  
            ?>  
        </td>

        <td><input type="text" name="nama_barang" id="nama_barang2"/readonly>
            <script type="text/javascript">
               <?php echo $jsArray; ?>
               function changeValue2(id){
               document.getElementById('kode_barang2').value = kode_barang[id].name;
               document.getElementById('nama_barang2').value = kode_barang[id].desc;
               };
            </script>
        </td>

        <td><input class="valOne" type="text" name="qty"></td>
        <td><input class="valTwo" type="text" name="harga_beli"></td>
        <td><input class="result" type="text" name="jumlah"></td>
    </tr>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("theTable").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        var row = e.target.parentNode.parentNode
        var val1 = row.querySelector(".valOne").value
        var val2 = row.querySelector(".valTwo").value
        row.querySelector(".result").value = val1 * val2
        })
    </script>
 </tbody>

    <td><input type="submit" value="OK"></a>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
</table>
</form>
</HTML>
```

And this is the connection to my database:

```
<?php
include "koneksi.php";

$kode_barang=$_POST['kode_barang'];
$nama_barang=$_POST['nama_barang'];
$qty=$_POST['qty'];
$harga_beli=$_POST['harga_beli'];
$jumlah=$_POST['jumlah'];

$query ="INSERT INTO faktur (kode_barang, nama_barang, qty, harga_beli, jumlah) VALUES ('".$kode_barang."', '".$nama_barang."', '".$qty."', '".$harga_beli."', '".$jumlah."'), ('".$kode_barang."', '".$nama_barang."', '".$qty."', '".$harga_beli."', '".$jumlah."')"; 
$sql =mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if ($sql){
header ("location: faktur.php");
}else{
echo "Error.";
        echo "<br><a href='input_faktur.php'>Back</a>";
}
?>
```

Notice that my 'Kode Barang' is a dropdown option, and everytime a user click an item ID, name of the item will be shown automatically in 'Nama Barang' column. Everything in this page works perfectly.

But, when I saved it to database, it didn't save both of the items (item in the first row and the second row). Database only saved the second item but saved it twice. When I add a row to the table become 3 rows, database only save the third item and save it three times. When I add `[]` to the name, like `name=kode_barang[]`, database didn't save the item ID, but only show "Array" text.

Would anybody please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: `<td type="text" name="kode_barang" id="kode_barang1"/readonly>` far as I know, `<td>` has no type or name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same name for both your fields
use a array 
`name="nama_barang[]"` `and  name="kode_barang[]"`

do a loop in the php to save each field individually